# How to connect to a locally running REPL via Leiningen?

Tags: java, spring, clojure

I have a Spring Boot application in which I create a REPL as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68503880).

That is, I have the following code:

```
@Service
public class ClojureRepl {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("CLOJURE");

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        final IFn require = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "require");
        require.invoke(Clojure.read(MAIN_CLOJURE_NAMESPACE));
        Clojure.var("clojure.core.server", "start-server").invoke(
                Clojure.read("{:port 5555 :name spring-repl :accept clojure.core.server/repl}")
        );
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        Clojure.var("clojure.core.server", "stop-server").invoke(
                Clojure.read("{:name spring-repl}")
        );
    }
}
```

When I start the application and enter `nc localhost 5555` on the command line, I am able to connect to that REPL.

I want to try out using nRepl as a client.

So, I tried entering

```
lein repl :connect 127.0.0.1:5555
```

It only outputs

```
Connecting to nREPL at 127.0.0.1:5555
```

and then nothing happens.

**How can I connect to the server REPL using `lein repl`?**

Comment: Lein wants an nREPL and not the simple socket REPL coming with clojure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in Clojure server in [clojure.core.repl](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.server) just starts a socket server with a plain text protocol, this is why it works [well with telnet](https://clojure.org/reference/repl_and_main#_launching_a_socket_server).

Leiningen uses the nREPL protocol. If you want to use it, try opening the server using the [nREPL](https://nrepl.org/nrepl/usage/server.html) library with `nrepl.server/start-server`.